# Can I convert my v-brakes to cartridges?

Tags: brakes

I have a Hybrid that uses v-brakes:

[image]

The brake pad has an attached threaded post and to change the pads I have to change the whole unit.

[image]

Can I change the pad/post unit to a cartridge type used on road bikes?

Maybe not this specific one, but similar:

[image]

or is the adjustment done in a different way? I know the whole pad/post ones have domed washers for adjustment.

Comment: There is plenty of brand(kool stop,etc) selling brake pad housing/holders. Most of it just use a small clip pin to hold the pad in place.  You must look for V-Brake holders, as the brake holder shown in your diagram just too short to be fixed on vbrake.

Comment: Bare in mind that, don't expect compatibility of replacement pad from different brand.

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of cartridge pads for MTB v-brakes.
For example http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cartridge-V-Brake-Pads-with-Titanium-Finish-for-Shimano-XTR-XT-SRAM-9-0-Avid-/200719390579?hash=item2ebbced773:g:auQAAOSwJSJXGDxZ .

Comment: Ah! They look a lot closer to what I need. The ones I found on wiggle didn't seem to have the same post / washer arrangement. Thanks